# How to run Google Vision API label detection and safe search detection in a single request in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-vision

The [Google Vision API pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/vision/pricing) states that [Safe Search Detection](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-safe-search) is free with [Label Detection](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/labels) for up to 5,000,000 requests per month. To me, this implies that there should be a way to run both label and safe search detection in a single request, but I cannot find how to do it.

I am calling Google Vision API from a Node.js program, by using the [Node.js client provided by Google](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-vision).

When calling [`safeSearchDetection`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/vision/latest/v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.html#safeSearchDetection), passing only an image path as a parameter, I get the safe search results back, but an empty array for labels (`labelAnnotations`), as exemplified below.

**Code snippet**:

```
const visionClient = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
const [ result ] = await client.safeSearchDetection('./resources/wakeupcat.jpg');
console.log ({ result });
```

**Output**:

```
{
  result: {
    faceAnnotations: [],
    landmarkAnnotations: [],
    logoAnnotations: [],
    labelAnnotations: [],
    textAnnotations: [],
    localizedObjectAnnotations: [],
    safeSearchAnnotation: {
      adult: "VERY_UNLIKELY",
      spoof: "VERY_UNLIKELY",
      medical: "VERY_UNLIKELY",
      violence: "VERY_UNLIKELY",
      racy: "VERY_UNLIKELY"
    }
  }
}
```

The other way around happens when I call the [`labelDetection`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/vision/latest/v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.html#labelDetection) function. We get valid `labelAnnotations`, but we get null as `safeSearchAnnotation`.

How can I make a call to run a safe search detection, using the Node.js client, in such a manner that the `labelAnnotations` are also returned?

I am afraid that if I make two calls (one for label detection and another for search safe detection), I will be billed twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, it is indeed possible to make a single request to get both labels and safe search results (having safe search for free in this case, up to 5M monthly requests).

We just need to use the [`annotateImage`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/vision/latest/v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.html#annotateImage) function, passing an [`AnnotateImageRequest`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/vision/latest/google.cloud.vision.v1.html#.AnnotateImageRequest) parameter, specifying label detection and safe search detection as features:

```
const visionClient = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
const visionRequest = {
  features: [
    { type: 'LABEL_DETECTION' },
    { type: 'SAFE_SEARCH_DETECTION' },
  ],
  image: { source: { filename: './resources/wakeupcat.jpg' } },
};

const [ result ] = await visionClient.annotateImage(request);
```

By doing this, `result` includes `labelAnnotations` and `safeSearchAnnotation`.